# Read OData from cURL request which was Returning Blank or Zero response

Tags: api, curl, soap, odata, microsoft-dynamics

From last 1 week i was trying to resolve this issue related to `cURL` returning blank response, while i'm retrieving data from cURL. After a long research i got that i'm having authorization issues. But after applying all positive feedback related to these kind of problem. I'm still unable to access that data. 
If i used to get data from browser: I getting that perfect `XML`. (Which i attached) 
But, if i'm using `cURL` or and `SOAP API` library I'm getting this kind of blank response after hitting that API.

    Please help to get any response from that URL of `ODATA`. 

 **XML URL**: (getting RAW XML) : 
[RAW XML for data retrieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bF6lA.jpg)
Following code i used to retreive from this URL:

```
    $baseURL = 'http://139.5.19.140:7048/DynamicsNAV71/OData/Company';
    $CompanyName = 'B. Jain Pharma-2017';
    $pageURL = $baseURL."('".rawurlencode($CompanyName)."')".'/Mycustomer';

    $useragent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.1) Gecko/20061204 Firefox/2.0.0.1";
    $urlValue  = "/Page/Mycustomer";

    $username  = 'pharma0\erpuser';
    $pass      = 'pass@123';
    $handle = curl_init();    
    curl_setopt_array($handle, 
    array (
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT => $useragent,
        CURLOPT_USERPWD   => $username . ':' . $pass,
        CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH  => CURLAUTH_ANY,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => false,
        CURLOPT_URL  => $pageURL,
        CURLOPT_POST => 1,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
            'Method: GET', 
            'Connection: Keep-Alive', 
            'Content-Type: application/atom+xml,application/atomsvc+xml,application/xml;text/html;charset=utf-8',
            'Content-Length: 5685',
            'SOAPAction: "" ',
        ),
       // CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS     => $urlValue,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 180,
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
        CURLOPT_VERBOSE => true,
    )
    );   
    $response = curl_exec($handle);
    var_dump (curl_error($handle));
    curl_close($handle);
    var_dump($response);
```

Please Help for this. Thank you much in Advance. Your support was really appreciable.

---

Comment: 1) OData allows you to retrieve the data in JSON, by adding `?$format=json` to the url
2) Check if the http error code is "no content 204" ... then its the user agent string

Comment: thank for your valuable response @MichaelSchönbauer ,, But still returning blank page with zero string, in cURL response.

Comment: can you post the response headers please?, can you try `CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH => "CURLAUTH_BASIC"` instead ANY

Comment: @MichaelSchönbauer Yes previously i also tried this `CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH => "CURLAUTH_BASIC" `  but still having same issue.

Comment: can you post the response headers? did you forget to use `$urlValue` here 
`$pageURL = $baseURL."('".rawurlencode($CompanyName)."')".'/Mycustomer';`
instead hard coding `/Mycustomer` into pageURL? do you really want to hard code the request length header to 5685? can you try to remove this header and the SOAPAction header as well? can you try to completely remove the CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER thing

Comment: can you try to remove most of the CURLOPT Parameters?
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER seems wrong. CURLOPT_POST seems to be wrong (you want to GET) 
CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION seems to be irrelevant, CURLOPT_RETURN_TRANSFER -> try to remove all that as well

Comment: @MichaelSchönbauer Yes i tired all these aspects. But i receiving blank response.  After a long research over ODATA & XML response i got that if i want required result i need XML response from SOAP URL only instead of OData response. Because XSD was no longer supported by PHP and if start receiving response data from Odata URL then after we have to use further parser library to parse data and retrieved data from XSD to PHP. So for time saving and removing complexity from this module i need to rework over NAVISION API XML response. But still i look for this question if there's possibility.

Comment: A response is never 'blank', please post the headers and the status code from the response.